# The difference between a var and function in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, var

I have been having problems understanding the difference between a var and a function.I have tried to  search it on internet and i wrote the same thing inside a var and  function and i got the same results.I would really like a explanation to tell me when to use var and when to use function.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you please provide some more information, such as what code you tried and the results that code gave?

Comment: "i wrote the same thing inside a var and function and i got the same results" -- if you could show us the code you wrote, we might be able to help you understand.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean this:

```
function foo() {
    // ...
}
```

Produces the same result as this:

```
var foo = function() {
    // ...
}
```

You've just discovered that the functions are [First class citizens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_citizen) in JavaScript. There are almost no differences between the two syntaxes. The latter is useful when manipulating functions as objects (e.g: `var foo = bar`, `bar` being a function) but has no real interest when it's about static functions.

One difference between the two syntaxes is that you can call a function before it is declared, but not when it's a variable:

```js
foo();

function foo() {
    console.log('foo');
}

bar();

var bar = function() {
    console.log('bar');
}
```

Note that you can reassign a function like you would do with a variable:

```js
function foo() {
    // ...
}

// Reassign the function with a string
foo = 'bar';

try {
    foo();
} catch(e) {
    console.error(e);
    console.log('foo:', foo);
}
```